# How can a parent pass overriding style rules to a child in styled-components fashion?

Tags: styled-components

I have a Button and a few other versions of the button that would like to reuse Button but override a few specific rules. Like width, height, color, or hovered state color etc.

Is this possible without having to manually pass in every single property as a prop?

Here is the example in webpackbin http://www.webpackbin.com/VyjrMGJ9f

```
import React from 'react';

import styled from 'styled-components';

const Button = styled.button`
  text-align: center;
  font: bold 15px helvetica;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 0;
  pointer-events: ${props => props.disabled ? 'none' : 'auto'};
  color: ${props => props.disabled ? '#848484' : '#fff'};
  background-color: ${props => props.disabled ? '#bebebe' : '#07314d'};
  &:hover {
    background-color: ${props => props.disabled ? '#bebebe' : '#336086'};
  }
`

const EnhancedButton = styled.button`
  background-color: ${props => props.disabled ? '#bebebe' : '#ec4800'};
  &:hover {
    background-color: ${props => props.disabled ? '#bebebe' : '#f98d00'};
  }
`

export default function HelloWorld() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
      <Button disabled>disabled button</Button> 
      and 
      <Button>button</Button>
      </p>
      <p>
      How can EnhancedButton in a different component re-use all of Button's rules and override some of them (in this case the background color and hovered background color? 
      <EnhancedButton disabled>disabled enhanced button</EnhancedButton>
      and 
      <EnhancedButton>enhanced button</EnhancedButton>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I just figured this out, so simple.

```
styled
```

can either take a tag or a component as an arguemnt, so in this case all I had to do was to change

```
const EnhancedButton = styled.button`
```

to

```
const EnhancedButton = styled(Button)`
```

Here's the working version on Webpackbin http://www.webpackbin.com/VyjrMGJ9f